# Encompassing term for software and data in a system

Tags: architecture, terminology

I am writing up a description/guide/wiki of an "open source software framework for the easy integration and utilization of datasets, algorithms, tools, and computing resources". I feel like software integration framework sounds concise and to the point, but I want to emphasize that it can also independently integrate and process standalone data (i.e. data meaning something like columns of numbers in a text file, even if that particular example isn't technically correct).

Also might as well take the chance to learn some new software development nomenclature. So I ask - is there some term that encompasses both data and software in software architecture?

Comment: No, though the question sounds ill formed I didn't realize it could be considered spam, good point though. I'll edit that part out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like a SOA [service oriented architecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service-oriented_architecture).  It also sounds very broad, almost like a full operating system minus the hardware layer.

I can't say that I've ever dealt with software that doesn't interact with data, whether it be imaginary like run time states or solid like blocks of bytes, so I'm not sure that trying to find a phrase for "software that acts on data" is like a fish trying to find a phrase for "fish that swims in water," because it's just assumed.

Comment: I thought there was some specific term for it that was escaping me, but you're probably right

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a perfect opportunity to coin some catch-phrase! How about: "external data fusion" for the process of the software architecture consuming data.

Comment: Probably doesn't apply here but I would be seriously tempted to use that phrase somewhere else were opportunity to present itself.